# Programming I/O ports as a user

Tags: c

I was trying the following example of I/O ports from [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/IO-Port-Programming.html).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<asm/io.h>

#define baseport 0x378

int main()
{
 if(ioperm(baseport,3,1))
  {
    perror("ioperm");
     exit(1);
  }
  outb(0,baseport);
  exit(0);
}
```

I'm using `gcc -o port ports.c` (the above code) which was advised in above link. But it's giving me the following error i.e.

```
ports.c:3:19: fatal error: asm/io.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
```

Is there any other header file to include instead of asm/io.h or any other way of doing it (it's a simple program)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might well depend on your implementation, `ioperm` is not standard.

On Linux with a modern `glibc`, you'll need `<sys/io.h>`, and your code is also missing `<stdlib.h>` (for `exit`).